# Why are Borg ships kept so hot?

Tags: star-trek

In the *Star Trek* movie *First Contact*, Jean-Luc Picard mentions something about the environment on deck 16 being like a Borg ship. Lt Worf states the temperature as 39.1 degrees Celsius (102.38 deg F) with a relative humidity of 92 percent.

The effective humidex is 69.4 Deg C (156.9 Deg F). This would kill most lifeforms including Picard's crew, with the exception of Lt Data, in a very short time.

How do the Borg and all the assimilated species survive such conditions?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/a12kyh/why_are_borg_shipsso_hot/

Answer (score 4):

This is simply impossible to answer without opinion based conjecture.

With that said, the Borg are fused organic machines...they will have a specific and optimum temperature at which their organics and machine parts run optimally.

This is normal for all things, including [machines](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214785318304218), [electronics](https://www.twi-global.com/technical-knowledge/faqs/faq-at-what-temperature-do-conventional-electronics-packages-fail), [batteries.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4526891/)  and you guessed it, living organisms.

Star Trek is a space show with hundreds of thousands of space aliens that all exist with different requirements. On earth there are plenty of organisms that live in a [huge variety of extremes](https://www.toptenz.net/10-organisms-can-survive-extreme-conditions.php). Space is no different.

Apparently the optimum temperature of Borg existence is 39.1 C and relative humidity of 92%.